# Website renders well locally but not when I push the code via FTP

Tags: ftp, render, web-development-server

I am trying to do this website www.educatedrent.com.
I can render all the pages perfectly locally but when I push the code via FTP or I check the website it looks as if there was no CSS and all the elements of the code are messed up. Any idea what this could be?

If I check my dev tools of google for example on my local index.html I have the following errors:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
include.preload.js:465 Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://fjhoaacokmgbjemoflkofnenfaiekifl/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
util.js:208 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Thank you!

Comment: What do Chrome's developer tools say? Most likely a wrongly-linked CSS: Remember on Windows `A.CSS` and `a.css` are the same file - on Unix (i.e. a web server) they are not.

Comment: @EugenRieck I edited my questions, have a look!

Comment: I was talking about the dev tools on the pushed page, the one that doesn't render properly.

Comment: Ah, it's online! You have a 404 on 4 css files!

Comment: @EugenRieck so how to I fix it? Why do I have a 404 on 4 css files?

Comment: Either you didn't push all files, or you have capital letters in file names

Comment: @EugenRieck i have uploaded all the files I am really sure of it and I have no capital letters. What else could it be?

Comment: It is definite: The css files don't load, because the webserver can't find them (Error 404) - so they are either not there or wrongly named.